# Mathjax does't work in django when linebreaks filter is used in django-template,but renders successfully without this filter

Tags: django, mathjax

Mathjax does't work in django when linebreaks filter is used in template that is  `$$ {{text|linebreaks}} $$` doen't work but `$$ {{text}} $$` renders successfully . But the problem is it's not responsive hence linebreaks filter is needed.
Is there anyway that mathjax can render and be responsive (changes with screen-size)

Comment: Are you just looking for http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output.html#automatic-line-breaking ?

Comment: thanks for the link and I tried linebreaking code, but it doesn't work. And there are no spaces between two words too.